# AngularJS: Using a directive correctly

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am relatively new to angular and have not yet begun using my own custom directives. I'm after some direction if this is the right situation to attempt and use one.

I have a log in system where a user will be given a set of roles depending on what their access to the system is. At the moment this means that if you have access you will be able to view an additional column that allows you to edit and delete, otherwise you can just view the table contents.

There are 3 possible roles and the user object has a list within it storing which of these roles they have access too,

```
{ "FirstName": "test", "Roles": { "1": true, "2": true, "3": true } }
```

These roles, or list of numbers ranging from 1-3, are then stored in a cookie so they can be used to constantly evaluate what the user can and cannot see.

My issue is then how do I apply these role checks in the html? At the moment I have a very crude method of sending the role value this way -

```
<td align="center" ng-show="CheckRoles(1)">
```

Obviously having the role hardcoded like this is bad... What I *think* might be the best method is to create custom directives called sysadmin, admin, user etc and then depending what visibility an html element should have you could add multiple amounts of these directives.

I guess I'm asking more if this would be a good approach? And if so what would be a good outline of setting it up?

Thanks

Comment: Your current approach looks fine to me, and is very flexible: you can combine role checks with `||`, you can use `ng-if` instead of ng-show, you can combine role checks with other kinds of checks, etc. I would just give meaningful names to the roles rather than 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I might just stick to my current method and do some slight modifications to it like you are suggesting then, maybe I was overthinking it. I'd still like to put the method check roles in a directive though because otherwise I might need to create that checkroles method in the different controllers that it will need to be used on different pages?

Comment: You can put this function in the $rootScope and make it available everywhere. Or you can put it in a service and expose the functions in controller scopes that need it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll have a go at doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after (assuming your user object called 'user')?

```
<td align="center" ng-show="user.Roles[1]">
```